# Deleting won't nullify until save : is it true?

Tags: macos, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-data

My situation :  I have complex (24 entities, many relationships and many ordered to-many relationships) model in `Core Data`.

Now let's say, I have an entity `PlayList` and an entity `Song`, and in `PlayList` an ordered to-many relationship to `Song`. This relationship has an inverse, and both have a `nullify` delete-rule.

I have remarked that when I delete a `Song` (let's call it `gangnam`) that belongs to a `PlayList`, this song is not removed from the relationship !! I tried to fix this with the following :

- I fixed the Apple's bug related to the to-many ordered relationships, using the excellent : [KCOrderedAccessorFix](https://github.com/CFKevinRef/KCOrderedAccessorFix). By the way, be careful if you use other solutions, because the bug is not only for the `addAnObject` part but also for the `removeAnObject` part. **Result : much better but still not working** :  my relationship still refers to `gangnam` :(
- I tried : `processPendingChanges` : **not working**.

Now,

- If I `save` my context, the `Song` `gangnam` is removed.

So, my question is :

**Do I have to `save` my context if I want to `nullify` the relationships ? 
Or am I missing something ?**

I tried to reproduce the "bug" with a smaller model, but in this case, calling `processPendingChanges` is enough to `nullify` the relationship. So, if anyone has encountered the same problem/situation, I would be happy to know that I am not the only one to fight with `Core Data` ;)

Comment: For a reason, the graph of the entities was not coherent (some bug of `CoreData` I guess, the relations and their inverse are not properly maintained). So, it refuses to delete the object. If I save, it first makes the graph coherent and then it is possible to remove the object.

Answer (score 0):

For a reason, the graph of the entities was not coherent (some bug of `CoreData` I guess, the relations and their inverse are not properly maintained). So, it refuses to delete the object. If I save, it first makes the graph coherent and then it is possible to remove the object.